# cloudControl: how to update custom config addon with new key/value pair?

Tags: cloudcontrol

I have custom config addon set up and it contains some info already, entered on the addon deployment phase using following syntax (https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Custom%20Config):

```
$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME addon.add config.free --PARAMETER_NAME=PARAMETER_VALUE
```

I'm wondering if there s a way how to update config in order to add (or remove) additional key/value pairs without removing whole addon and adding it again with the old code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already possible as of [cctrl 1.8.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cctrl):

```
$ [sudo] pip install cctrl --upgrade

$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config.add PARAMETER_NAME1=PARAMETER_VALUE1 PARAMETER_NAME2=PARAMETER_VALUE2 PARAMETER_NAME3

$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config
PARAMETER_NAME1=PARAMETER_VALUE1
PARAMETER_NAME2=PARAMETER_VALUE2
PARAMETER_NAME3=true

$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config.remove PARAMETER_NAME1

$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config PARAMETER_NAME1
[ERROR] Key `PARAMETER_NAME1` not found.

$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config.add --force PARAMETER_NAME2=PARAMETER_VALUE4

$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME config PARAMETER_NAME2
PARAMETER_VALUE4
```

[Config add-on documentation page](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Custom%20Config) has been updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not, but it's a planned feature.

Comment: too bad, the addon is pretty useless for development then

Comment: I can only agree ... without the option to add, remove or update existing values it is not possible to make zero downtime deployments when anything depends on those vars.